# Hide permanently password attributes from Prisma Database Query

Tags: mysql, reactjs, database, next.js, prisma

I want to make a database request to get all the jobs linking with the User's data.
How can I remove the attribute of the user's password being fetched?

```
    const job = await prisma.jobs.findMany({
      where: {
        id: Number(id),
      },
   
      include: {
        User: true, // I want to hide the user s password
      },
    });
```

I tried this [Github Page](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5042), but had no success.

Comment: REST API is universally used for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by following query:

```js
const job = await prisma.jobs.findMany({
  where: {
        id: Number(id),
  },
  // Returns all job fields
  include: {
    User: {
      select: {
        name: true,
        // Every other user fields except password
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Here is the reference section which will be helpful: [Include with select](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/select-fields#include-relations-and-select-relation-fields)